# "À" para definição de tempo

Tags: gramática

Finalmente terminei de criar todas as legendas que precisava, então agora vou revisar toda a ortografia e gramática.

Dentre as frases, uma delas indicava tempo, a qual eu erroneamente, por culpa do editor de legendas bastante espartano (u.u'), havia escrito com ***há***:

> Daqui há uma hora

Erroneamente porque, já que indica tempo futuro, eu deveria usar apenas a preposição ***a***.

No entanto, após corrigir a frase:

> Daqui a uma hora

Fui informado pelo corretor ortográfico de que deveria crasear esse ***a***:

> Daqui à uma hora

[Eu pesquisei](http://www.usinadetextos.com.br/lingua-portuguesa/revisor/a-uma-hora-ha-uma-hora-a-uma-hora/) e vi que a crase desse cenário deve vir quando o tempo definido é exato mas, além de ser uma frase coloquial, bem sabemos que quando dizemos algo nesse sentido não é **exatamente** uma hora.

Poderiam explicar?

Comment: Para um português é muito fácil saber quando escrever ***a*** ou ***à*** porque pronunciamo-los de forma diferente desde que aprendemos a falar; agora, como explicar?

Comment: Daqui a uma hora (a) preposição (uma) artigo indefinido feminino singular. Para haver crase tem de ocorrer encontro vocálico, ou seja, duas vogais iguais.

Comment: Você tem alguma referência sobre isso, @AndréLyra? Digo quanto a necessidade do encontro vocálico ser entre vogais **iguais**? Porque desse jeito, aquilo que foi sugerido pelo corretor ortográfico (que teoricamente tem saber um pouco mais que a gente) estaria errado

Comment: Reparei agora que *daqui a uma hora* e *daqui à uma hora* estão ambas corretas mas têm significados diferentes. Vou emendar a resposta.

Comment: E tendo agora lido o artigo com atenção, creio que ele quase de certeza não se aplica ao teu *daqui a uma hora* (mas depende exatamente do que queres dizer). Pormenores na resposta.

Comment: encontro vocálico = encontro de vogais

Comment: @AndréLyra   daqui a **uma** hora -  neste caso não é artigo indefinido, e sim um numeral. "daqui a uma hora",  "daqui a duas horas", "daqui a três horas".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na dúvida, faça como a Roberta Close, troque o sexo. Se ficar "ao", então é "à". Se ficar "a" mesmo, então é "a" também.

"Daqui a um minuto"

ou

"Daqui ao um minuto"?

Fácil de ver que a primeira expressão é correta, e a segunda, errada. Portanto, "daqui a uma hora".

Se inverter o gênero for difícil, faça a viagem de volta. Se você volta "da", é por que você foi "à". Se você volta "de" é porque você foi "a".

"Fui a França"

ou

"Fui à França"?

Se quando você voltar, voltar **da** França, então você foi **à** França. Mas se você voltar **de** França, é por que você foi **a** França (no caso, ambas as expressões são válidas, embora "de França" tenha um certo sabor arcaico, pelo menos no Brasil).

A lógica é esta: **"à"** é a contração da preposição "a" com o artigo definido feminino "a": **a+a = à**. Se, portanto, a palavra regida da preposição "a" for masculina, e pedir artigo, teremos **"a"** (preposição) + **"o"** (artigo), que têm de formar **"ao"**. E se trocarmos a preposição "a" pela preposição "de", então a contração será **"de"** (preposição) + **"a"** (artigo), que têm de formar **"da"**.

Mas atenção, por que há uma exceção importante: quando a palavra "moda" está implícita, como no *bacalhau à Gomes Sá*. Embora o Gomes Sá seja homem, o que se quer dizer é *bacalhau **à moda** de Gomes Sá*; como a moda elidida é do gênero feminino, pede a crase.

Se ficar muito difícil decidir, porém, não use crase, e fim. É melhor não saber e pronto, do que pensar que sabe sem saber. Antes o erro popular do que a hipercorreção. E a falta da crase pode passar por erro de digitação, o excesso não.

Comment: para este caso sua resposta não vale, pois o 'uma' ali significa ou "em uma hora" ou "na hora de número 1"

Comment: Explicação sensacional, simples, direta e humorada. Você teria alguma referência para esse "truque"?

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Referência não tenho, mas a lógica é esta: **à** é a contração da preposição "a" com o artigo definido feminino "a": **a+a = à**. Se, portanto, a palavra regida da preposição "a" for masculina, e pedir artigo, teremos **"a"** (preposição) + **"o"** (artigo), que têm de formar **"ao"**. E se trocarmos a preposição *"a"* pela preposição *"de"*, então a contração será **"de"** (preposição) + **"a"** (artigo), que têm de formar **"da"**.

Comment: Mas atenção, por que há uma exceção importante: quando a palavra "moda" está implícita, como no *bacalhau **à** Gomes Sá*. Embora o Gomes Sá seja homem, o que se quer dizer é *bacalhau **à** moda de Gomes Sá*; como a moda elidida é do gênero feminino, pede a crase.

Comment: Complementa a resposta com esses comentários pra eu bater o martelo

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Feito.

Answer (score 5):

Quer ***daqui a uma hora*** quer *(saio) **daqui à uma hora*** são gramaticais, mas têm significados diferentes. Para facilitar a explicação suponhamos que são agora dez da manhã. Então:

> (a) São agora 10 da manhã. Daqui **a uma hora** serão 11 da manhã.
>
> (b) Saio daqui **à uma hora** da tarde.

Imagino que o que queres escrever seja algo do tipo de (a) (caso contrário terias com certeza incluído o *saio* ou *parto* ou equivalente), mas é possível que o corretor ortográfico esteja a confundir com o *à uma* das frases do tipo (b).

[O artigo lincado na pergunta](http://www.usinadetextos.com.br/lingua-portuguesa/revisor/a-uma-hora-ha-uma-hora-a-uma-hora/) não se aplica ao ***uma hora*** da frase (a). O artigo aplica-se apenas à indicação de um momento durante o dia: uma da tarde, duas da manhã, 23h30, etc. O *uma hora* da frase (a) não é um momento — nem uma da manhã, nem uma da tarde — é um intervalo de tempo, 60 minutos. Em (a) ***a*** é a preposição, que é invariável independentemente de ser daqui **a uma hora** ou **a duas horas** ou **a 15 minutos**:

> São agora 10 da manhã. Daqui **a duas horas** será meio-dia [não *daqui às/as duas horas*].
>
> São agora 10 da manhã. Daqui **a 15 minutos** serão 10h15 [não *daqui aos/os 15 minutos*].

Se fôssemos lógicos deveríamos dizer *de agora a uma hora*, mas o uso consagrou *daqui a uma hora*.

O artigo aplica-se ao *uma hora* de frases de tipo (b): indicação, não de intervalos de tempo, mas sim de momentos no tempo. Em (b) ***à*** é a contração da preposição ***a*** com o artigo definido ***a***. Ora o artigo varia em género e número. Portanto neste caso depende se é **à uma hora** ou **às duas** ou **ao meio-dia**:

> Saio daqui **às duas horas** da tarde [preposição ***a*** + artigo definido ***as***].
>
> Saio daqui **ao meio-dia** [preposição ***a*** + artigo definido ***o***]

Do mesmo modo diríamos:

> Encontro-me contigo **às** onze horas ou **ao** meio-dia ou **à** uma da tarde. É como preferires.

Pode não ser óbvio, mas nesta construção a indicação de horas exatas necessita de artigo, tal como em:

> O relógio bateu **as** sete horas
>
> Entre **as** dez da manhã e **o** meio dia

Agora se nos referirmos a um momento indeterminado durante o dia, naturalmente não podemos usar o artigo definido. Usamos novamente a preposição ***a*** com um pronome ou artigo indefinido:

> Posso encontrar-me contigo **a** qualquer hora.
>
> Posso encontrar-me contigo **a** uma hora qualquer.

Comment: O que você quis dizer é que o 'uma' em algum caso não seria artigo mas numeral. Bem difícil captar essa diferença em uma frase solta já que os artigos também podem contar (um e uns, umas e umas. a e as, o e os).

Comment: "*Quer daqui a uma hora quer daqui à uma hora são gramaticais, mas têm significados diferentes.*" A diferença é que "daqui" é ligado a "a uma hora" num caso, e ao verbo "partir" no outro: *Parto... daqui a uma hora*. *Parto daqui... à uma hora". No primeiro caso, é uma expressão; no segundo, uma junção gratuita de palavras.

Comment: @Luís , É verdade. mas poderá vir daí a embirração do corretor ortográfico com o *a uma*.

Comment: @Jacinto É verdade. Em princípio, não confiemos nos corretores ortográficos. O meu pelo menos, me proíbe de usar vocativos; se escrevo "João, traga-me o processo", ele me adverte que não posso pôr vírgula entre sujeito e objeto. E quando escrevo a alguém de sobrenome "Lemos", sempre me diz que não, José Carlos não Lemos, José Carlos Leu.

Comment: @Luís Essas são de gritos.

Comment: @Jacinto - Há porém uma circunstância em que "daqui à uma hora" é uma expressão, com o "daqui" ligado a "à uma hora". É quando o "à" tem o sentido de "até à": "*Daqui à uma hora, faltam quinze minutos*".

Comment: @Luis Também me lembrei dessa. Parece-me uma construção válida, mas não encontrei exemplos reais. Imagino que tenhamos tendência a dizer, «até à uma hora ainda faltam...» em vez de «daqui à uma hora ainda faltam...»